# How do I clear the (read-line) buffer in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, stream, console, buffer, readline

I'm writing a text-based game in clojure, and noticed a strange issue with (read-line).

I have a function to slowly print out the text, one letter at a time. After printing, it prompts the user to enter a command.

The problem is, any key that was pressed BEFORE the prompt will still be included when the user presses enter.

For example, if you accidentally press "x" while it's printing, then enter "look" in the console, it reads it as "xlook".

Is there a way I can clear previous key presses, i.e. get a fresh input stream for (read-line)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that the call to read-line happens synchronously after the last letter was printed?

Comment: Could you post your code? It's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing what your code is actually doing.